# Image path showing on Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

On my home page of a build I'm doing in WordPress, I wanted to make the background color on the header/menu transparent. When I changed the CSS to make the header transparent, I'm seeing the path to the image now.

I can't find where it is coming from.

Help would be appreciated.

http://www.aaworksite.com/chez

Thanks

Comment: please use proper explanation with code which you are using

Comment: Please embed your code within the post, as per SO guidelines.  You can also include a link, but we need questions and answers to be self contained, for if the link becomes unavailable, then the question and page becomes useless. Additionally it makes for a better user experience to not *require* users to go clicking all over the internet just to find your question.  You also increase your chances at getting quicker and better answers.  Click `edit` to embed. All the best.

Comment: Hi Sheryl, the page is a Wordpress template. I added the link to the page in the original query. If I embed the code from the page, I thought it would be the "live" code, not the original code from the template.

Answer (score 0):

You have your " " on different lines with your path in the middle on it's own line. It's not reading it as "yourlinkpath", it's reading it as :

"

yourlinkpath

"

Comment: This was added by the template. I didn't do it. How do I remove it?